# Confusing System.SocketException thrown on a call to BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

I've got an exception (System.SocketException) being thrown on the (I believe, second call to System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive) that I do not understand why is being thrown. I'm trying to receive, and respectively append data that is received to a per-client MemoryStream object. This results in the received event never being fired, and some data not appended to the stream.

```
    static void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // our client socket
        var client = (Client)ar.AsyncState;

        // amount of bytes received in this call (usually 1024 for buffer size)
        var received = client.socket.EndReceive(ar);

        if (received > 0)
        {
            // append to memorystream
            client.stream.Write(client.buffer, 0, received);
        }
        else
        {
            // raise event done
            ClientSent(client, client.stream.ToArray());

            // clear out the memorystream for a new transfer
            client.stream.SetLength(0L);
        }

        try
        {
            // continue receiving
            client.socket.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, client.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, (AsyncCallback)EndReceive, client);
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            // error thrown every single time:

            // System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket 
            // is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied'
            return;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException disposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you closing the connection after each message is received.  Look at the msdn example.  The examples use Sockets but you can use any class that inherits the socket like TcpListener or TcpClient : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I don't close the connection. What do you mean?

Comment: Following line is wrong : client.BeginReceive((AsyncCallback)EndReceive, client);  See msdn example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It's not, I should have mentioned I created my own BeginReceive method in the Client class, just so that I don't have to pass buffer, offset or length. I updated the post without my custom methods.

Comment: I bet you need to use this. client.socket.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, client.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, (AsyncCallback)EndReceive, /*client*/ this);

Comment: var client = (Client)ar.AsyncState; <--will not be around for the next portion.

Comment: The client that raised the event is not always the same client that should be picking up on the other end of the async callback?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what caused this particular error. But after some tinkering I got the EndReceive method working correctly. Here's my new design:

```
    static void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var client = (Client)ar.AsyncState;
        var received = 0;

        try
        {
            received = client.socket.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            client.socket.BeginDisconnect(false, (AsyncCallback)EndDisconnect, client);
        }

        if (received > 0)
        {
            client.stream.Write(client.buffer, 0, received);

            if (client.socket.Available == 0)
            {
                var sent = client.stream.ToArray();
                client.stream.SetLength(0L);

                Console.WriteLine("Client sent " + sent.Length + " bytes of data");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            client.socket.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, client.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, (AsyncCallback)EndReceive, client);
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException disposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: BeginReceive should have a new AsyncCallback and use ar.AsyncState.  I tried last year to use a seperate method like you are trying to use and made similar mistake.  You are sending the client.buffer but are getting client at top of method.  The msdn example it is both state.